# Wireless doesn't work reliably on an Acer Aspire 8930 with an Intel wifi link 5100

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

2 days ago I've upgraded my ubuntu to 12.04. It's running dual boot with windows 7 on an acer aspire 8930 which has a intel wifi link 5100.

I now have  wifi problems where it constantly switches on and off and has e really weak signal.

Could anybody help.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel WIreless with the Linux Kernel has always not worked well. This is the workaround to get it to work properly:

1. Press Ctrl + Alt + T. Type in this command: `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/intel_11n_disable.conf`
2. Paste this into the gedit windw that opens: `options iwlagn 11n_disable=1`
3. Save, and close gedit. When back at the prompt type `sudo update-initramfs -u`.
4. Run `sudo modprobe -r iwlagn && sudo modprobe iwlagn`.
5. Try it out!

Hope that helps!
Source:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/871254